# Detecting a change in a compound property

Tags: properties, swift, observable

Objective-C would not allow you to run the following code:

```
myShape.origin.x = 50
```

This made it easy to detect changes in the origin, since someone using your class was forced to write `myShape.origin = newOrigin`, and thus you could easily tie in to the setter of this property.

Swift now allows you to perform the original, formerly-disallowed code. Assuming the following class structure, how would you detect the change to the origin in order to execute your own code (e.g. to update the screen)?

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
}

class Shape {
    var origin: Point = Point()
}
```

**Update:** Perhaps I should have been more explicit, but assume I don't want to modify the Point struct. The reason is that Shape is but one class that uses Point, there may very well be hundreds of others, not to mention that the origin is not the only way a Point may be used.

Comment: You're probably talking about some specific case of `shape` and `origin`, because actually this construction: `object.subobject.x = 50;` runs fine as long as `x` has a setter (`x` is not readonly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property observers (`willSet` and `didSet`) **do** fire when sub-properties of that property are changed. In this case, when the `x` *or* `y` values of the `Point` structure change, that property will be set.

Here is my example playground code:

```
struct Point : Printable 
{
    var x = 0
    var y = 0

    var description : String {
    {
        return "(\(x), \(y))";
    }
}

class Shape
{
    var origin : Point = Point()
    {
        willSet(newOrigin)
        {
            println("Changing origin to \(newOrigin.description)!")
        }
    }
}

let circle = Shape()

circle.origin.x = 42
circle.origin.y = 77
```

And here is the console output:

```
Changing origin to (42, 0)!
Changing origin to (42, 77)!
```

Comment: That is exactly what I meant in my answer. If the OP did try it and it did not work for him, he's hitting some compiler bug.

Comment: This works, I was accidentally typed class Point instead of struct Point.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
class Shape {
   var origin: Point {
   willSet(aNewValueForOrigin) {
       // pre flight code
   }
   didSet(theOldValueOfOrigin) {
       // post flight code
   }
   }
}
```

Edit: revisited code and added name of arguments to reflect what to expect.

Comment: It should work. If it does not it's some bug. `Point` is a structure and structures are value types. Therefore (modulo optimizations) they behave as if they were fully copied/reassigned whenever one of the fields change.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `()` after the declaration of the class? I have not seen this and just curious if there is something I am missing from the Swift language. (I noticed the OP does this as well)

Comment: Because I was lazy and did a cut and paste of the OP code. Edited now (not home, cannot test the code so I'm writing it by memory).

Comment: You're right, this does work, I reversed my vote, thanks for the answer! @SiLo: I was typing fast and was in the habit of closures, fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Property Observers also works for structs

[Link to the part on the ebook](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

```
class StepCounter {
    var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
    willSet(newTotalSteps) {
        println("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
    }
    didSet {
        if totalSteps > oldValue  {
            println("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
        }
    }
    }
}
let stepCounter = StepCounter()
stepCounter.totalSteps = 200
// About to set totalSteps to 200
// Added 200 steps
stepCounter.totalSteps = 360
// About to set totalSteps to 360
// Added 160 steps
stepCounter.totalSteps = 896
// About to set totalSteps to 896
// Added 536 steps
```

Comment: This works, thanks. If you edit your post I can reverse my vote.

Answer (score -1):

Use `didSet`, e.g.,

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0
    var y: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        println("blah blah")
    }
    }
}

class Shape {
    var origin: Point = Point()
}

let s = Shape()

s.origin.y = 2
```